# Summing Values from SQLite into EditText

Tags: java, android, sqlite

in my app i have an sql database that holds an item name and its litres, I have a list view that prints out each row, in each row i am printing the name of each item and a plus and minus button. when a button is pressed I want the litres of that item to be added to a running total. I just cant get it to work and would really appreciate any help I can get.

At the moment I am reading the litres for each item into a variable 'test' I am then sending this variable to print in the edittext through an interface but when I click a button the editText doesnt get the litres it just prints out some sort of string.

This is the adapter where I am trying to read in the litres, Should I be trying to do this here or somewhere different?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

//public int counter = 0;
public ArrayList<Integer> counter;
private MyAdapterInterface mMyInterface;

public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, MyAdapterInterface myInterface) {

    //instantiating the values
    super(context, cursor);
    this.context = context;
    this.mMyInterface = myInterface;

    //array to sort each value per row
    counter = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    //default all counters to 0
    for(int i=0; i<cursor.getCount(); i++)
    {
        counter.add(0);
    }
}
Context context;


@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    // when the view will be created for first time,
    // we need to tell the adapters, how each item will look
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

    return retView;
}

public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {

    //getting the first value for the custom row (the item name)
    TextView textViewItemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item1);
    textViewItemName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(1))));


    final TextView test = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item1);
    test.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(2))));

    //editText for custom row
    final EditText runningTotal = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.runningTotal);

    //setting up the plus button
    final Button plusButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.plusButton);
    plusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        private int counterPos;

        public void onClick(View v) {
            //code to change the value of the editText and the array, not working

            //cursor.getPosition() returns the position in the list
            counterPos = counter.get(cursor.getPosition());

            //increments the number at counterPos
            counterPos++;

            //set the new value to the array position
            counter.set(cursor.getPosition(), counterPos);

            //changes the editText in middle of row
            runningTotal.setText(Integer.toString(counterPos));

            //sends counterPos to the interface for the running total
            mMyInterface.updateEditText(test);
        }
    });

    //setting up the minus button
    final Button minusButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.minusButton);
    minusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        private int counterPos = 0;

        public void onClick(View v) {
            //code to change the value of the editText and the array, not working

            //cursor.getPosition() returns the position in the list
            counterPos = counter.get(cursor.getPosition());

            //decrements the number at counterPos
            counterPos--;

            //sets the new value to the array position
            counter.set(cursor.getPosition(), counterPos);

            //changes the value of the editText in the middle of the row
            runningTotal.setText(Integer.toString(counterPos));

            //send value to the interface for the running total
            mMyInterface.updateEditText(test);
        }
    });
}
}
```

My interface

```
//interface to change the editText(running totals) on the main activity
public interface MyAdapterInterface {

public void updateEditText(TextView value);
}
```

Comment: Please post the code of the updateEditText implementation in the adapter.

Comment: it is printing some text because you're passing a `TextView` object to your interface. If you need to get a `String` value out of that Textview, you need to call `TextView.getText()`.

Comment: thanks for the reply guys but I got it all sorted, updated my post to show the new adapter

Comment: To answer a question, write an answer.